# Add Array Index using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I want to add a kind of line number or identifier with jolt for each array element.

Given Array:

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "neyN": "valueN"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "neyN": "valueN"
  }
]
```

Expected Result:

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "neyN": "valueN",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "neyN": "valueN",
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

I tried now default, shift and more, but was not able to find a right solution.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance
Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spec 1 :** Group the keys along with id field using index number.

**Spec 2 :** Remove the index number key from the result array.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&1",
        "$": "&1.id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

All that you need is to bring the objects' indexes through use of $ wildcard while keeping the current values, and do all in arraywise manner. Only the following single spec will accomplish this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[&1]",
        "$": "[&1].id"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]